# Bitlocker device name change

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, encryption, bitlocker

When imaging our PCs we generally create a temp name for our facilities to change the device name to whatever particular department fits their needs. The issue is we can't send out any devices without encryption, we happen to use Bitlocker throughout the enterprise. When we Bitlocker our devices with their temp names, Bitlocker uses the temp device name and it shows up when entering the encryption password. When our technicians at our other facilities go to rename our temp names, the temp name does not change in Bitlocker. This causes confusion among our users and some of our techs when asking for device names for our ticketing system and when troubleshooting. Anybody here have any suggestions for this particular issue?

Comment: Where are they seeing the previous temporary name?

Comment: At the Bitlocker log in screen where they are prompted to enter the Bitlocker password.

Comment: Stupid question: Aren't the devices member of a Windows domain, or do they lack a TPM chip? Or why do your users even have to enter a TPM password at boot time?

Comment: We work in the medical field and devices are required to be encrypted in case they are stolen. Having a password at boot via Bitlocker is an added security measure for our devices.

Answer (score -1):

Bitlocker likes to tie in to hardware configuration, the level of the tie in can be controlled with the PCR registers (also applies to win 7):

http://blog.mpecsinc.ca/2007/11/windows-vista-bitlocker-error-system.html

When migrating bitlocker encrypted system:

**Fully Decrypt the drive before imaging**, than image it with password encryption. Do not just suspend the bitlocker protection, it wouldn't work properly on a new machine. after resumed.

You can set image password in paragon or acronis true image.

If you need to encrypt separate image file, I would consider using winrar with password or truecrypt.

They are way more portable then bitlocker.